# The last inserted rowid of a specific table in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert, rowid

Is there a way to get the last inserted rowid of a specific table in SQLite3? There is a function [last_insert_rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) which returns the rowid of the most recent successful INSERT into a rowid table or virtual table. However, I want to know whether there's such an method to get the last inserted rowid of a specific table.

Comment: Not reliably, no. `SELECT max(rowid) FROM yourtable` will usually work if nothing is inserting rows with user-specified rowid values though.

Answer (score 3):

The last inserted `rowid`s of all tables are stored in the [internal table `sqlite_sequence`](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab), which you can query like any other table. Make sure your primary key ID has the attribute `autoincrement`, else it isn't listed there.

```
sqlite> create table Test1 (id integer primary key autoincrement, text string);
sqlite> create table Test2 (id integer primary key autoincrement, text string);

[...]  -- Insert rows here

sqlite> select rowid from Test1;
id        
----------
1         
2         
sqlite> select rowid from Test2;
id        
----------
1         
2         
3
sqlite> select * from sqlite_sequence;
name        seq       
----------  ----------
Test1       2         
Test2       3
```

Comment: Beware race conditions. Be sure to wrap your operations in a transaction if you will use these stored sequence values to manipulate your tables. You want to lock out concurrent INSERTs or the values may change under you.

Answer (score 1):

Below might be the simplest and the most reliable way – just use the `Returning` clause with `RowId`:

```
insert into MyTable (Column1, Column2) Values (Val1, Val2) Returning RowId;
```